# loss of rights on webapps during a Maven deployment

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, rights

How to specify to Maven to put the right rights on included files? When I deploy my spring application on the Tomcat server, I lose the rights to the files deployed in the webapps directory. So, for future deployment, I can not delete existing files and I have to ask my host to put the right one. He told me it was during the war that the problem occurred but I do not know how I can tell Maven to put all the rights on the files.

Comment: Are you deploying a war file on a unix platform ?

Comment: yes it's unix platform

Comment: And, are you logged with the same user that runs tomcat or with another user ? When you deploy a war to a tomcat instance it is unpacked  by tomcat and the files are created with the user that runs tomcat.

Comment: no, i'm not the tomcat owner because it's a remote host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a maven problem. When you deploy the war tomcat unpack it with its ownership. You have to delete the war or update it using tomcat itself. 
You can use the tomcat manager for this task.

Comment: Please, if I have answered to you question, could you mark it as solved?